# Azure Monitoring REST API - (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, rest, azure-monitoring

I need to send a custom metric to Azure Monitoring REST API:

Documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview

And I found a sample code that I adapted here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/17687

My adapted code looks like this:

```
  public static class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId: "xx",
            clientId: "yy",
            clientSecret: "zz");

            // Note the region specific URL used here. See
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-custom-overview#supported-regions
            var monitorClient = new MonitorClient(
                subscriptionId: "myid",
                endpoint: new Uri("https://monitoring.azure.com"),
                credential);

            await monitorClient.CreateAsync(
                resourceGroupName: "can be left empty",
                resourceProviderNamespace: "can be left empty",
                resourceType: "can be left empty",
                resourceName: "can be left empty",
                new { });
        }
    }

    public class Metric
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public MetricData Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetricData
    {
        public MetricBaseData BaseData { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetricBaseData
    {
        public string Metric { get; set; }
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> DimNames { get; set; }
        public MetricSeries Series { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetricSeries
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> DimValues { get; set; }
        public double ping { get; set; }
    }

    public class MonitorClientOptions : ClientOptions
    {
    }

    public class MonitorClient
    {
        private readonly string _subscriptionId;
        private readonly Uri _endpoint;
        private readonly HttpPipeline _pipeline;

        public MonitorClient(
            string subscriptionId,
            Uri endpoint,
            TokenCredential tokenCredential,
            MonitorClientOptions options = null)
        {
            options ??= new MonitorClientOptions();

            // Note the use of ".default" here. Without this, authentication
            // fails with a message "AADSTS70011: The provided request must
            // include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the
            // input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope
            // https://monitoring.azure.com/ is not valid…".
            _pipeline = HttpPipelineBuilder.Build(
                options,
                new BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy(tokenCredential, "https://monitoring.azure.com//.default"));

            _subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
            _endpoint = endpoint;
        }

        public virtual async Task<Response> CreateAsync(
            string resourceGroupName,
            string resourceProviderNamespace,
            string resourceType,
            string resourceName,
            object parameters,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            // prepare a metric to publish
            var parameters2 = new Metric
            {
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Data = new MetricData
                {
                    BaseData = new MetricBaseData
                    {
                        Metric = "Switch G0",
                        Namespace = "Brussels",
                        DimNames = new string[] {
                            "Ping"
                        },
                        Series = new MetricSeries
                        {
                            DimValues = new[] {
                                "Ping"
                            },
                            ping = rnd.Next()
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            using var message = CreateRequest(
                resourceGroupName,
                resourceProviderNamespace,
                resourceType,
                resourceName,
                parameters2);

            // This fails with a message "The access token is intended for the
            // wrong audience or resource. It should exactly match (including
            // forward slash) audience 'https://monitoring.azure.com/'.".
            await _pipeline.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return message.Response.Status switch
            {
                200 => message.Response,
                _ => throw new Exception("Something when wrong: " + new StreamReader(message.Response.ContentStream).ReadToEnd()) // Forgive this line.
            };
        }

        private HttpMessage CreateRequest(
            string resourceGroupName,
            string resourceProviderNamespace,
            string resourceType,
            string resourceName,
            object parameters)
        {
            var message = _pipeline.CreateMessage();

            var request = message.Request;

            request.Method = RequestMethod.Post;

            var uri = new RequestUriBuilder();

            uri.Reset(_endpoint);
            uri.AppendPath("/subscriptions/", escape: false);
            uri.AppendPath(_subscriptionId, escape: true);
            uri.AppendPath("/resourceGroups/", escape: false);
            uri.AppendPath(resourceGroupName, escape: true);
            uri.AppendPath("/providers/", escape: false);
            uri.AppendPath(resourceProviderNamespace, escape: true);
            uri.AppendPath(resourceType, escape: true);
            uri.AppendPath(resourceName, escape: true);
            uri.AppendPath("/metrics", escape: false);
            uri.AppendQuery("api-version", "2018-09-01-preview", true);

            request.Uri = uri;

            request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

            // Here `parameters` should represent the custom metric, and this
            // should be serialised here. For this repro, the content doesn't
            // matter.
            request.Content = RequestContent.Create(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This can be anything, since auth will fail."));

            return message;
        }
    }
```

However I am getting this exception:

```
Message "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found." string
```

Any idea of what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you use POSTMAN for this task?

Comment: no, it has to be a .net console app